# AutoFill Method of range Class failed trying to paste formula

Tags: excel, vb.net

I’m creating an Excel file and I write a fomula on an specific cell (G8 for example) what I want to is to replicate that formula to the end of my row (GI8) I’m trying to use AutoFill method but this gives me an error.

Here is my code

```
Dim src = oBook.Worksheets(2).Range(“G8”)
Dim rng = oBook.Worksheets(2).Range(“H8:GI8”)

src.AutoFill(Destination:=out, Type:=Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillCopy)
```

What I’m doing wrong and how can I solve ir?

Comment: How is the Range `out` defined (`Destination:=out`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb209671(v=office.12)), your destination range must also include the source range. Because your `rng = oBook.Worksheets(2).Range(“H8:GI8”)` and your `Dim src = oBook.Worksheets(2).Range(“G8”)`, these do not overlap. Try making your `rng` overlap, like below.

`rng = oBook.Worksheets(2).Range(“G8:GI8”)`